# Is it possible to use slice() in Quick Sort?

Tags: javascript, slice, quicksort

I am learning Quick Sort and here is the code below:

```
const pivot1 = (arr, low = 0, high = arr.length -1) => {
    let pivot = arr[low];
    let index = low;

    for(let i = low + 1; i <= high; i++){
        if(pivot > arr[i]){
            index++;
            [arr[index], arr[i]] = [arr[i], arr[index]]; 
        }
    }
    [arr[low], arr[index]] = [arr[index], arr[low]];

    return index;
}

const quickSort1 = (arr, low = 0, high = arr.length - 1) => {
    if(low < high){
        let pivot = pivot1(arr, low, high); 
        quickSort1(arr, low, pivot - 1);
        quickSort1(arr, pivot + 1, high);
    }
    return arr;
}

console.log(quickSort1([5,2,1,8,4,7,6,3]));  // [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
```

However, if I do not want to set `low` and `high` parameters, and try to use `slice()` in `quickSort2` function expression, it seems like something wrong with the sorting and I have no idea (recursion does not work as expected). Could someone tell me why is that and if I am as stubborn as a mule to use `slice()`, is it possible that I can still let the function work?

p.s., I change the pivot as the last element in `pivot2` function expression, so `pivot2` is a little different from `pivot1`.

```
const pivot2 = (arr) => {
    let pivot = arr[arr.length - 1];
    let index = -1;

    for(let i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++){
        if(pivot > arr[i]){
            index++;
            [arr[index], arr[i]] = [arr[i], arr[index]];
        }
    }
    [arr[arr.length - 1], arr[index + 1]] = [arr[index + 1], arr[arr.length - 1]];

    return index + 1;
}

const quickSort2 = (arr) => {
    if(0 < arr.length - 1){
        let pivot = pivot2(arr);
        let left = arr.slice(0, pivot);
        let right = arr.slice(pivot + 1);
        quickSort2(left);
        quickSort2(right);
    }
    return arr;
}

console.log(quickSort2([5,2,1,8,4,7,6,3]));  // [2,1,3,8,4,7,6,5]
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not use slice as it does not alter the array underneath. You can either pass left and right index, or save the results of the two recursive quicksorts and merge the array.

```
const left_array = quickSort2(left);
const right_array = quickSort2(right);
arr = [...left_array, ...right_array];
```

also the right slice would have pivot as argument instead of pivot+1 as slice doesn't include end index.

[Slice MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)